# Have a different style set in different sections of the same Word document

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, microsoft-word-2013

I have a document "template" (not yet a template file type - I hope to create that as described below) for a report. The report is broken up into different sections:

```
Letter to the Client
Table of Contents
Section I
    Title Page
    Body
        1.0
        2.0
Section II
    Title Page
    Body
        1.0
        2.0
Appendix A
    Title Page
    Body
Appendix B
    Title Page
    Body
```

Each major "metasection" (Letter, Sections I and II, Appendices) has different formatting requirements. In order to avoid having a huge number of styles (e.g. `Normal - Letter`, `Normal - Sections`, `Normal - Appendices`), it would be nice if I could have the same style name be different depending on which section of the document it is found in. Or said another way, I would like for a document to have multiple style sets depending on the section.

An example of what I am after: for the `Letter` section I would like `Normal` to be 10 pt Times New Roman, but in `Section I` and `Section II`, I would like it to be 11 pt Garamond. Or as a second example: the `Title` style should be left aligned on the letter, but centered in the appendices.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

EDIT:

From the comments below it seems like VBA would be the only option to do this. My initial idea on how this could be done would be:

1. The user simply applies the `Normal` style, `Title` style, etc, as necessary.
2. The VBA code would be written so as to have a style registry of corresponding `Normal`s and `Title`s, etc., for each document section (`Normal 1`, `Normal 2`, etc).
3. Write a routine which iterates through the styles being used in the document, selects all the parts with that style, and applies the style from the registry depending on the section.
4. The routine is executed with a simple command button, or when the document is saved, or printed.

Any further additional suggestions or alternative ideas on this are appreciated.

(Apologies if this has been asked before; I searched for a similar question but couldn't find one. )

Comment: If you keep the separately formatted sections in different files, there are Word add-ins that claim to retain the formatting. Using Word to merge them directly will mess up the formatting.

Comment: If you already have a template with the correct formatting, why do you need to change anything?

Comment: @harrymc What I actually have is a mess (just a .docx document with all the correct formatting, but doesn't use styles, and that I am loosely referring to as a "template"). I am working with people who are unfamiliar with styles and it will be difficult (if not impossible) to get them to use `Normal-Letter Page` and `Normal- Main Sections` and `Normal - Appendices`. Just not going to happen. But I *might* be able to get them to click on `Normal`, `Heading 1`, `Title`, etc.

Comment: @mpez0 Thanks for the suggestion, but separate files would just cause other problems.

Comment: I think that only a VBA macro can do the job, meaning that your template will use the Normal style, and the macro will selectively change it to Normal-Letter etc. by section. One question will be when to execute that macro and whether a reverse-macro is also needed.

Comment: @harrymc I was afraid of that. I've done a lot of VBA programming in Excel but not Word, though I know they're similar. However, this sounds pretty onerous. :( I suppose the simplest thing to do would be to make a button that applies the styles when clicked- I guess that wouldn't be too hard. And when clicked again it could go back to the "regular Normal".

Comment: Word VBA is normally in a better shape than that of Excel. If you have lots of experience with VBA, then you are better qualified than me for the job.

Comment: [this may be of use](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/macrosvba/ResetStyles.htm)